# Javascript issue with output

Tags: javascript

I have a program in js that is supposed to check for the carry number of a problem ie 55+20 = 0 carry number and total value = 75. There is something wrong with the check answer and I can't seem to figure out what it is. However when I use this method it doesn't give the correct output and says every answer is wrong.

```
var topNumber = new Array();//top number
topNumber[1] = "35"; 

var bottomNumber = new Array();//bottom number
bottomNumber[1] = "20";

var answer = Array();//answer
answer[1] = "55"; 

var carryover = new Array();//carry over number
carryover[1] = "0"; 

//create arrays to store user information

var userCarry = [];

var userAsn = [];

//creates user values

var userCarry1 = "";

var userAsn1 ="";

//sets the number of questions to zero
var qnumber = 0;    
//creates a function to display the page number, math problem, and an alert to save the user name.
function nextQuestions() {
    //every time the user clicks on the button the number will increase and will display question number and it will be used to display the rest of the question information.
    qnumber = qnumber + 1;  
    document.getElementById('questionNumber').value = qnumber;
        //sets up question numbers with qnumber is equal to a specific question number.
    switch (qnumber) {
        case 1: 
        // question number and question
        document.getElementById('topQuestionNumber').value = topNumber[1];
        document.getElementById('bottomQuestionNumber').value = bottomNumber[1];
        //creates values to store the user information
        userCarry1 = document.getElementById('carryOverNumber').value;
        userAsn1 = document.getElementById('answerNumber').value;
        break;  


//creates a function that will check if the user value is equal to the answer

function checkAnswer() {
    if((answer[1] == userAsn1) && (userCarry1 == carryover[1])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct!" + userCarry1 + userAsn1);
    }
     if((answer[2] == userAsn2) && (userCarry2 == carryover[2])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry2 + " "+ userAsn2);
    }
     if((answer[3] == userAsn3) && (userCarry3 == carryover[3])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry3 + " "+ userAsn3);
    }
     if((answer[4] == userAsn4) && (userCarry4 == carryover[4])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry4 + " "+ userAsn4);
    }
     if((answer[5] == userAsn5) && (userCarry5 == carryover[5])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry5 + " "+ userAsn5);
    }
     if((answer[6] == userAsn6) && (userCarry6 == carryover[6])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry6 + " "+ userAsn6);
    }
     if((answer[7] == userAsn7) && (userCarry7 == carryover[7])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry7 + " "+ userAsn7);
    }
     if((answer[8] == userAsn8) && (userCarry8 == carryover[8])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry8 + " "+ userAsn8);
    }
     if((answer[9] == userAsn9) && (userCarry9 == carryover[9])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry9 + " "+ userAsn9);
    }
     if((answer[10] == userAsn10) && (userCarry10 == carryover[10])) {
        alert("Your answer is correct! "  + userCarry10 + " "+ userAsn10);
    }
    else {
        alert("Your answer is wrong.");
    }


}
```

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Where is the end bracket of the switch statement? And of the first function?

Answer (score 1):

my best guess is that you are messing with variable type

topNumber[1] = "35" telling the program that it's a piece of string, not int

I would try topNumber[1] = 35; and parseInt() the user input to be safe to compare

Comment: I tried that with the parseint var userCarry = parseInt(document.getElementByld('carryOverNumber').value); and doesn't help much.

Comment: @RobG `35 == "35"`, but `35 + "35" == "3535"`

Comment: @some—you're right, but the issue is that the equivalence test is failing, it doesn't get to the addition/concatenation.